# How to Setup Perfmon to Automaticaly Start an "Alert" At System Startup?

Tags: windows, perfmon

I have an "Alert" setup in perfmon, but it gives me only two options to start it:

1. Manualy
2. At an specified time (schedule)

So...

**How to Setup Perfmon to Automaticaly Start an "Alert" At System Startup?**

I know I can type "`logman start {alert-name}`" to start the alert, but how to run this command automaticaly at system startup?

One solution is to create a .bat with this command and leave it at "Startup" folder. But, it would require to logon to trigger this .bat.

So... what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create a "Scheduled Task" to run on system startup. Have a look at "Schedule" properties of a task and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: Like Evan says...create your batch file and then create a scheduled task to run the batch file at startup.

Answer (score 3):

Try a computer startup script: Start | Run | gpedit.msc | Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Scripts (Startup/Shutdown).

Answer (score 2):

There's a better way if you're on Windows Server 2008. You can use Task Scheduler to run a data collector set at startup without having to use batch files:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/jeff_stokes/archive/2011/11/16/how-to-sustain-your-data-collector-set-through-a-reboot.aspx