# Running perfmon continuously with periodic reports

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, performance-monitoring, perfmon

I have a question very similar to [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/63354/automatically-start-windows-server-2003-perfmon-counter-log-upon-reboot) one, but I want to continuously run perfmon, during reboots and throughout the day. Further, I'd like to generate a perfmon report every 10 mins or so. The original question tells me how to run perfmon when the server is restarted, but I don't know how to make perfmon continuously run while throwing periodic files.

I've tried setting it as a scheduled task that needs to be done every 10 mins, but this is too sloppy, and when the scheduled task kicks another instance, the current perfmon report writer crashes, and I get a garbage report. I've also tried writing a sloppy batch script that would fire off the task at scheduled intervals, but this is the same problem as the scheduled task. I'm sure I'm just missing something silly, but I don't see it.

Ideas? (If it helps, I'm running Windows 7 locally, and I'm trying to set up the processes for boxes running Windows 2008.)

Answer (score 1):

You may have already found a solution to you problem. In case you're still looking for the answer,
check this URL [Taming Perfmon: Data Collector Sets](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2012/02/27/taming-perfmon-data-collector-sets.aspx).

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged. You're encouraged to either provide a brief description of what's on the other side of the link, or quote the relevant text with the link as citation.

Comment: Thanks for the link Arun, I'll check out the link when I get some free time and update you on my findings.