# Perfmon counters are not restarted after reboot

Tags: scheduled-task, perfmon, performance-counters, reboot

The question has a long history, and I went through all previous questions ([1](https://serverfault.com/questions/63354/automatically-start-windows-server-2003-perfmon-counter-log-upon-reboot?noredirect=1#comment1117884_63354), [2](https://serverfault.com/questions/20692/how-to-setup-perfmon-to-automaticaly-start-an-alert-at-system-startup)) but neither of them answers the question **why the standard way doesn't work**? If I don't want to use `logman` how can I schedule automatic  restart of counters/data collectors after (re)boot?

I set up [PLA tasks](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/jeff_stokes/2011/11/16/how-to-sustain-your-data-collector-set-through-a-reboot/), set [stop conditions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722312(v=ws.11).aspx) and schedule conditions in perfmon, but counters are not started. Is it a fundamental bug or I'm doing smth wrong? Or maybe it is working only in server systems? I have Win10 Pro.